# Flutter Permission Handler not re-asking for permission if already denied

Tags: flutter, dart, permission-denied

I am trying to access the microphone of the users device, I have managed to integrate the permissions_handler package somewhat successfully. When I clicked the mic icon the request permission message popped up as expected but I pressed deny to deal with that scenario but now, when I click the mic icon no message pops up because I have already denied permission. My question is, how I can re-ask user for their permission if they haven't granted it before? Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class InsideLeft extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InsideLeftState createState() => _InsideLeftState();
}

class _InsideLeftState extends State<InsideLeft> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Icon(Icons.mic),
        onTap: () async {
          var status = await Permission.microphone.status;
          switch (status) {
            case PermissionStatus.granted:
              print('Granted');
              break;
            case PermissionStatus.denied:
              print('denied');
              await Permission.microphone.request();
              break;
            case PermissionStatus.restricted:
              print('restricted');
              break;
            case PermissionStatus.undetermined:
              print('undetermined');
              break;
            case PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied:
              print('Permanently denied');
              break;
            default:
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use the openSettings(); provided by the permission handler packaget which opens the settings of your app and ask the user to allow the permission , that's the only way around if the user denies permission

Answer (score 8):

As noted [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/permissions/), you cannot request permission again on iOS, after it was denied. You have to take the user to the Settings app and let them give your app the permission manually.

[App Settings](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) is a great package for this, especially their `openAppSettings` method.

[image: Requesting permission after it was denied]